# Referencing columns and string within own defined function python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a function which has 3 parameters:
`country_metric(df, country, column)`

this is there[parameters]  individual function.

`df` - dataframe

`country` - a string (which can be assumed to be an entry which will be found in a column called `location`)

`column` - a string (which can be assumed to be a column (other than location) which will be found in `df`

The function should return the value from the row for the given country and the column labelled as per the second string:

My function does not work as I do not know how to phrase the function properly.
this is is what I have so far:

```
def country_metric(df, country,column):
    for column in df:
        if df["location"] == country:
            return df[df["location"] == country]["column"]
```

I can't seem to find anything on stack about referencing columns within datasets whilst defining your own function. I tried using `.items()` as suggested by python and then it printed. and I'm struggling from here onwards.
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item'`

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with filter by column name, output is one eleemnt Series if only one `country` in `location` column, `Series` with 2 or more values if duplciated `country` or empty `Series` if not match `country`:

```
def country_metric(df, country,column):
    return df.loc[df["location"] == country, column]
```

If need first match value with no error if no matching `country` use `iter` with `next` trick:

```
def country_metric(df, country,column):
    return iter(next(df.loc[df["location"] == country, column]), 'no match')
```